# Integrating ExpressJS and MeteorJS

Tags: javascript, json, express, meteor

I have an Epress JS rest api that posts values to the mongoDB.  I'm wondering if it is possible to integrate Meteor JS to retrieve those values from the MongoDB.
Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Meteor's data layer connects to MongoDB, use a normal publish on the server and subscribe from the client. https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/collections

It won't matter that your Express app updates the db independently - Meteor's reactivity will pick up the changes as they happen.

Comment: Thanks a bunch, but I'm wondering if there are some techniques to do this ? I have a separate express app that posts info to the mongo db in port localhost:27017. I also have a meteor app that simply retrieves values from the mongoldb(localhost:3000). I'm not sure how I would be able to connect these two. Is there some meteor support to access the expresses mongoDB contents ?

Comment: You just need to set up an environment variable, like this: MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/database-name - Meteor will then connect to the db used by express

Answer (score 0):

In meteor for creating REST-API the first choice would be a publish-subscribe call but if you need to make REST-API beyond that you can use 'Restivus' high-level API.

Here is the [link](http://meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API)

Comment: Thanks, but I’m looking for a techniques in meteor framework to grab the mongodb values that are already posted using Express JS.